# entity framework many to many with sub groups

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many

I have a problem with a entity framework model. I couldn't find the answer also because i really don't know how to explain it well.

I have a User table anad a Rights table. There is a many-to-many relationship.
The EF User model has two properties: GrantedRights and RevokedRights.

From what i understood EF should create 2 tabel (one for the granted and the other for the revoked) with just the RightsID and the UserID.

But I can't find those tables, neither the context gives me the option. I didn't create the DB.

I'd like to know if there's an example code to follow to extract the list of GrantedRights from a user in this case..

Thanks

Comment: Are you doing this with Code First?  If so, can you post the model that you've created so far?

Comment: hi... I don't know where to get the model, but i found a system to retrieve that information... I just wrote that and it seems to work.. but seems i'm new with EF i really don't know. This is the query: